# Nested threading and handling it safely

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, task-parallel-library

I have an application which is using EWS2.0 API to enumerate the folders inside Inbox folder and download all attachemnts to a defined location. I am providing a sample code here to get an idea how my code looks like. I have no problem while enumerating and downloading attachments using EWS, instead problem is that since its running in a single thread ,so it took around 20-30 minutes to enumerate and download 10-15 attachments. So what I am thinking:

1. I will use multithreading or Parallel Tasks which ever fits in my case.
2. First I will count the total number of folders inside the Inbox. Then same no. 
      of threads will be created. Now in each folder, I will get count of the mails 
      to be enumerated and again will open the same number of threads if possible, 
      and so on.
3. Once the download is complete inside a thread, will cleanup that thread 
      there itself (if possible) otherwise will return back to its parent.

Skeleton of existing code:

```
static main()
{
  try{
       DownloadAllAttachmentsInsideInbox();
     }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    // handling 
  }
}
private void  DownloadAllAttachmentsInsideInbox()
{
  //core logic goes here
}
```

---

I would like to go something like this.

1. Main Thread - > DownloadAllAttachmentsInsideInbox()
2. Enumerate all directories inside this method and Create same number of threads.
3. Create Single thread for Single Folder and enumerate no. of mails with attachments in that thread.
4. Now get total number of emails and create threads for each mail in each folder and let download start separately in each thread.
5. All threads should be handled safely.

---

Finally I would like to say, i do not require any spoon feeding code , i just need any reference work link so that i can implement it as per my usage.

Comment: Before you go to all the trouble of adding multiple threads, you should determine where the bottleneck is. All that fancy stuff isn't going to help you if the reason it's slow is because your bandwidth is maxed out.

Answer (score 1):

Task Parallel Library is the best practice in this situation which gives you more control on the `threads` you created. I would like to call out one point in your statement

> I will count the total number of folders inside the Inbox. Then same no.of threads will be created

Suppose the folders count is 50 and you are creating 50 `Tasks` in a 4 core processor machine which can run only 4 `Tasks` simultaneously. TPL have the capability to manage all these `Tasks` in a queue and process one by one. Still creating more `Tasks` at a time has some overheads and these `Tasks` will competitive for the resources. You can create `Task` based on the demands to utilize resources properly.

`System.Environment.ProcessorCount` will helps you to get your machines no.of cores, based on this value you can create the Tasks. To know more about TPL please see the below link.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Use `async` and `await` to download the mails of each folder. To know more on

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Instead of downloading mails for all folders, download only the folder user want at that moment. e.g The way synchronization works in `Outlook`
eg: In outlook

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like that.  Queue email download tasks to a pool of threads that, typically, would be much larger than the number of available cores.  Flow-control it by keeping a pool of email-request objects that are created at startup and recycled back into the pool for re-use.

If you don't keep a lid on it, the number of threads/tasks will just run away.